# Angular2 - Unit test case not able to Mock Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am not able to mock user service, other service which I mocked are working fine. If I am commenting user service then unit test case is working fine. There are many components which are using user service. Unit test cases for all those components are not working in which user service is injected.

**Error :  Can't resolve all parameters for AlertService: ([object Object], ?, [object Object], [object Object]).**

Code for testing Alert service :

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BackendAlertService } from './backend-alert.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, ConnectionBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { ConfigService, LoggerService, UserService } from '../../shared/services';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
class MockUserService {
  private data$: Observable<Object>;
  readonly user$: Observable<any>;
  readonly privilege$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor() {
    this.data$ = Observable.of({ me: 'JindaR', fname: 'rohit' });
    this.user$ = Observable.of({ me: 'JindaR' });
    this.privilege$ = Observable.of([{ testing: 'true' }]);
  }

  hasPrivilege(privilege): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.of(true);
  }

}


@Injectable()
class MockConfigService {
  url$(url) {
    return Observable.of('testing.com');
  }
}

@Injectable()
class MockLoggerService {

}

fdescribe('BackendAlertService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        BackendAlertService,
        HttpTestingController,
        { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService },
        { provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        { provide: ConfigService, useClass: MockConfigService },
        { provide: LoggerService, useClass: MockLoggerService }
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([BackendAlertService], (service: BackendAlertService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Code for Actual service :

```
@Injectable()
export class BackendAlertService {

    constructor(
        private configService: ConfigService,
        private userService: UserService,
        private http: Http,
        private logger: LoggerService) { }

    /** Get Alerts */
    get(): Observable<Alert[]> {
        return Observable.of([]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47013640/1260204) not fix your problem or point to the fix of your problem would you please share the constructor and test code for `AlertService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bug. I am using like this :

```
import { ConfigService, LoggerService, UserService } from '../../shared/services'
```

Angular is not able to resolve it properly. I write it like below and it worked

```
import { ConfigService} from '../../shared/services/config.service';

import { LoggerService } from '../../shared/services/logger.service';

import { UserService } from '../../shared/services/user.service';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you either use `jasmine.createObjectSpy` or the following:

```
{
 provide: UserService,
 useValue: {
 hasPriviledge: _ => Observable.of(true),
 }
}
```

Comment: I am using the same method for others which I mentioned but it is not working only for UserService, Is there any bug? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When testing services I generally use this pattern. It uses [ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate](https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector#resolveAndCreate).

> Resolves an array of providers and creates an injector from those providers

- The `beforeEach` will call this before each test (`it`) and populate the local `backendAlertService` variable.
- The test code has full access to the `MockBackend` using `this.backend`
- The test code can check anything on the last connection using `this.lastConnection`
- The test code has access to all user defined types that are injected. The instances in this test setup are `this.userService`, `this.loggerService`, and `this.configService`.

Code:

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';

describe('Backend alert service tests', () => {

    var backendAlertService: BackendAlertService = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
        this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
            { provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
            { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions },
            { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService },
            { provide: ConfigService, useClass: MockConfigService },
            { provide: LoggerService, useClass: MockLoggerService }
            Http,
            BackendAlertService
        ]);
        backendAlertService = this.injector.get(BackendAlertService) as BackendAlertService;
        this.backend = this.injector.get(ConnectionBackend) as MockBackend;
        this.backend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => this.lastConnection = connection);

        // injected services/types that you want access to in your tests
        this.userService = this.injector.get(UserService) as UserService;
        this.loggerService = this.injector.get(LoggerService) as LoggerService;
        this.configService = this.injector.get(ConfigService) as ConfigService;
    });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(backendAlertService).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should get something', fakeAsync(() => {
    var results: Alert[];
    backendAlertService.get().subscribe(serviceResults => results = serviceResults);
    tick();
    expect(results).toBeDefined();
  }));  
});
```

Comment: AlertService is the service where UserService is injected.

Comment: @Rohit - Can you share the constructor for `AlertService` and the complete code the `AlertService` spec/test file? You can omit the code inside the `it(` blocks that is used for testing.

Comment: @Rohit - here is an answer with a complete test setup. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: I got this Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]

Comment: @Rohit - did you copy my entire spec setup above verbatim? Can you show the stack trace so we can see what line is failing?

Comment: Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]
    at invalidProviderError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/projects/psf-client-pcw/~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:1285:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/projects/psf-client-pcw/~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:2086:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _normalizeProviders (http://localhost:9876/_karma

Comment: Yes I copied the entire spec as it is.

Comment: Same thing is happening with the approach also. When I commented code for user service, It's working fine.

Comment: @Rohit could be your mock class. Try to replace the provider value with this: `{ provide: UserService, useValue: {} },`, if that fixes this error then it is your mock class.

Comment: Same Error : Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]

Comment: @Rohit - Did you import all your types including UserService at the top of the code file?

Comment: Yes I have done, All test cases are working fine except in which user service is injected, are not working. Should I share user service?

Comment: @Rohit - please do.

Comment: please review userService

Comment: I got the bug. I posted the solution. Thank you for your time.